# Accessing a nibble in a byte, appending it to the previous byte and then evaluating it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, byte, bit

I read in a set of 4 bytes.

```
b'\xc2\x0c\xe4\x8f'
```

This is little Endian data and, for example, I want to access a parameter that is the entire first byte and the lower (right side, B0-3)) of the second byte. So what I want to end up with is (in bin):

```
1100 11000010
```

Which is the lower half of the second byte first and then the first byte - which evaluates to 3266.

The code I have to do this is:

```
packet=b'\xc2\x0c\xe4\x8f'
bin_str = '0b'+((format(packet[1],'08b'[-4:])+format(packet[1],'08b'))
decoded_data=int(bin_str, 2)
```

This works as I expect it to, but I'm not sure it's the optimum way to do things. I have tried to use bitwise operations as well but getting the code to recognise that I want to take 1 and a half bytes and evaluate them with little endianess is eluding me. If it was two full bytes I would just use int.from_bytes() and no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting to string, doing text manipulations and converting back is not the way to go for such a simple task. Try this instead:

```
b = b'\xc2\x0c\xe4\x8f'
n = 0x100*(b[1] & 0x0F) + b[0]
```

The code above combines just few basic operations: retrieving a single byte, selecting bits with binary AND, etc.

In detail, there are 4 input bytes: `A B C D`.

1. `b[0]` retrieves byte `A`,
2. `b[1]` retrieves byte `B`
3. `B & 0xF` clears bits 7 to 4: `0 0 0 0 B3 B2 B1 B0`
4. `0x100 * value` (also `value << 8`): adds 8 zero bits (another null byte):

Finally, adding 1 + 4 gives us: `0 0 0 0 B3 B2 B1 B0   A7 A6 A5 A4 A3 A2 A1 A0`

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for, I knew I wasn't doing it in an efficient way. great explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

What about converting to int and doing a modulo operation on this?

```
input = b'\xc2\x0c\xe4\x8f'
num = int.from_bytes(input, "little")
result = num % (2**12)
```

Does this suit you needs?